# extracting callback values and assigning to a global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following function which makes an async call to another function, and receives a callback.

```
function wrapper(callback) {
   callArgos("fifa 17", function(response) {
           console.log("callback within the function " + response);
   });
```

The response here is a price, e.g. 40.00

Is there a way for me to assign the callback to a global variable?

I've tried defining a variable x = 0; outside of the function and assigning response to x, but I cannot access the value of response outside.

I've also read JS is pass by value rather than reference, so I guess what I am doing is never changing the original reference.

I also understand that the very nature of asynchronous calls means that printing the contents of x, even though I am logging it after calling 'wrapper' means that the contents of x is being printed out before wrapper has finished executing.

Is there a way I can assign the value of the callback to the global variable x without using another callback function?

I want to perform various checks on x in another function.

Apologies if there's a simple answer to this. I've looked at similar questions but they don't really help.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No; you can't escape async.  You should use promises.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll check out these promises, cheers!